# Json.Stringify messed up my date object

Tags: javascript, html, json, datetime, time

I have this variable 'previousDate' and assigned it to previous date.

```
var previousDate;
```

When i do a console.log(previousDate), i get this value at the console.

```
Wed Dec 07 2016 10:02:37 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Now, when i json.stringify this data, i get following date and time.

```
2016-12-07T18:02:37.223Z
```

The date is the same but please note the time here. Instead of PST, it is showing me GMT. I need to have the PST timing here too when i stringify. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To transfer date objects, it is usually simpler and less error-prone to do so with a UTC timezone.

Comment: I want the PST timings to be displayed after stringify. but its showing UTC i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript date values don't contain timezone information.

When you log something to the console, the browser does its best to show you relevant and useful information. For dates, that often means that whatever UTC value is stored within is displayed in your local timezone, which for you must be "GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)."

If you want to display the time in UTC, you can write:

```
console.log(date.toUTCString())
```

This is what `JSON.stringify` is doing under the hood; transporting dates with UTC helps simplify things when that information has to cross various timezones.

However, that behavior doesn't seem to be what you're looking for. If you want the string to be local-timezone when you send it, you can write:

```
console.log(date.toString())
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create your object, create a method to return a date string.
Sample:

```
var obj = { d1: (new Date()), d1String: function() { return this.d1.toString(); } }
```

Or save the YourDate.toString() in one property of your object.

```
var objDate = { dateString: YourDate.toString() ;}
```

Or

```
var ff = function(YourObject) {  var OBJ = {} ;
for(x in YourObject)
{
   if (typeof(YourObject[x]) !== "function")
       eval("OBJ." + x + " = '" + YourObject[x] + "'");
    else
      eval("OBJ." + x + " = '" + YourObject[x]() + "'");
}
var strOBJ = JSON.stringify(OBJ);
return strOBJ;
}
```

My Gist on GitHub

https://gist.github.com/kiaratto/afb6bb9acd21d0dda37157eb3a92ec2f

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can get what you want, if you do:

`date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.toTimeString()`